# SQL table output parsed in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, csv

Various discussions on this subject have gone all sorts of places, none of which appear to help consistently with an answer.

SQL puts the following text file out for me:

```
Line1;"alpha
  bravo
  charlie
"
Line2;" zulu
  yankee
  xray
"
```

Yes, the arbitrary whitespace and blank bottom entry is desired.

What I want in Excel is

```
+-------+----------+
| Line1 | alpha    |
|       |  bravo   |
|       |  charlie |
|       |          |
+-------+----------+
| Line2 |  zulu    |
|       |  yankee  |
|       |  xray    |
|       |          |
+-------+----------+
```

but it makes a pig's ear of the formatting.

If it is all one column, the newlines etc behave nicely and each delimited block of text ends up as a single cell containing multiple lines of text.

I've looked at encoding, search and replace limiters, csv vs txt extensions, breaking the encoding so Excel gives me a chance to manage the parsing, using my own delimiters.

Any ideas and suggestions would be gratefully received.

Thanks,
Thys

Comment: You don't show us the problem or your specific process. Show us the code that *SQL puts the following text file out for me*.

Comment: Hi Parfait.  The code is not the issue.  Parsing it in Excel is where the problem lies.  I can control the output all day long, but I can only get Excel to behave if I output a single column.  This will not work for my user audience.

Process is simple --  create a multi column CSV where one column has newlines in it, double-click the CSV file, Excel opens and chokes.

Creating multi column, multi row with no formatting, Excel is fine.  Creating single column with rows containing newlines, Excel is fine.